# Is it possible to update WSO2IS user password from an API endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to update wso2 identity server user password from an API endpoint. My scenario is when i click password reset button from my application, the given password should be updated in the WSO2IS. Is it possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by a PATCH request to SCIM2 endpoints. The following Curl command is to reset the password of a user by the admin. (use `/scim2/Users/<user-id>` and add the authorization header `<base64 encoded username:password of admin>`) (Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/patchUser)

If the reset is done by the same user, you can use `/scim2/Me` endpoint (Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Me%20Endpoint/patchUserMe) . Then the authorization header should contain the particular user's credentials or valid access token.

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/<user-id>' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "value": {
                "password": "newpassword"
            }
        }
    ],
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ]
}'
```

Comment: I'm trying to update a user's password by `scim/Users<user-id>` but I'm getting an error `[LDAP: error code 64 - naming attribute 'mail' is not present in entry]`

Comment: As per the LDAP error https://ldap.com/ldap-result-code-reference-core-ldapv3-result-codes/#rc-namingViolation. What is the exact endpoint tht use used to update password ?

Comment: I'm using https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/consuming-scim-rest-endpoints-from-a-java-client-application/. I've downloaded the java application and created a client to call the update method. This client first search for the User SCIM by username and  after set on this User SCIM object the new password. I've already tested the Create method and it worked. Only Update is not working :( @Anuradha Karunarathna.

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna what event will this api trigger under [[event_handler]] subscriptions?

Comment: Try `POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS` event